# php getting multiple post datas with a loop

Tags: php, loops, post

I have form that contains text inputs named like sample. It starts with option1 and goes to optionX. X is unpredictable.

```
<input type="text" id="option1" name="option1"/>
<input type="text" id="option2" name="option2"/>
<input type="text" id="option3" name="option3"/>
<input type="text" id="option4" name="option4"/>
```

I need to get only ones that contains a text in value with a php loop to insert them a database.

How can i pass empty post values (includes that contains only spaces) and get others to a php loop?

Comment: Input is seft closing tag in HTML. [Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Summary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(substr($key, 0, 6) == "option" && str_replace(" ", "", $value) != "" && strlen($value) > 0) {
        // this is one of the 'option' fields that isn't empty or has only a space
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of variable names that have content and use variable variables in the loop to use their values

Answer (score 0):

Try using `empty()` function checking whether `$_POST['x']` variable is empty or not.

If it's empty, just use `continue` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i <= count($_POST); $i++)
 { 
   $k = 'option'.$i;
   if(isset($_POST[$k] && !empty(trim($_POST[$k])))
     {
       echo $_POST[$k];//do anything with the value from post for option
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the value and then check if its empty.

Here's the link to trim() documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
And here's the empty() documentation link http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php

```
if (empty(trim(input_value))){
    //pass
}else{ 
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST as $formField=>$formValue) {  //loop over all the form fields...
    if strpos($formField, 'option') {         //and find the ones with "option" in them
        if (trim($formValue)) {               //if there is data besides spaces
             // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```